# Can two \vtop boxes exist side by side?

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, tex-core, boxes, plain-tex

So I am trying to see if I can put two `\vtop` boxes side by side.  The below is the closest I have gotten. This is a kind of a "plain-tex in latex" example.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,letterpaper,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya}[SmallCapsFont=Alegreya SC]

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\long\def\Lcv#1#2{\hskip-1.3in \hbox to 2in{\hfil\itshape #1}%
    \hskip.5in\hbox to 3in{#2\hfil}}

\def\Lup#1#2{\Lcv{\vtop{#1}}{\vtop{#2}}}

\begin{document}

    \Lup{Hello this is your\\Crazy Uncle Harry}{Who joined the mob%
\\to feel good\\about himself}

     Hello and \\ Welcome to {\itshape my} World!!

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the code these are not really acting like `\vtop` boxes in the sense that in order to break paragraphs a `\\` is needed.

I realize that there are various ways of accomplishing the same thing with various table environments and with `\halign` in plain tex. And that it is pretty simple to do so.

What I am looking for (if it exists at all) is a (hopefully simple) way of placing full `\vtop` boxes so that they are aligned along the baseline of a single line, "side by side".  If it really cannot be done without incredible code wrangling, then I would appreciate that answer.---Thanks all.

Comment: try `\hbox to 7cm {\vtop{\hsize=3cm Hello this is yourCrazy Uncle Harry}
\vtop{\hsize=3.5cm Who joined the mob to feel good about himself}}`

Comment: Oh, you put it into one big `\hbox`. I did not think of doing that. Nice!  You could also do that `\hbox to \hsize` to get the full margin's width, right?

Comment: yes you're right.

Comment: yes if you are in hmode, but since using latex simplest is `\parbox[t]{...}{...}\parbox[t]{...}{...}` which naturally come side by side as latex box commands always start hmode before starting the box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need to know for doing a "box arithmetic" is

- TeX changes vertical to horizontal mode at some places and returns back at others places.
- `\vbox` or `\vtop` has its width given as most wider element in it. If this is whole paragraph then the width is `\hsize`. So it is typical to set a width of `\vbox` or `\vtop` by `\vtop{\hsize= something ...}`

When TeX is in vertical mode, then `\vbox{...}\vbox{...}` places boxes one above second. But when TeX is in horizontal mode then `\vbox{...}\vbox{...}` places boxes at the same line. For example:

```
\leavevmode \vtop{...}\vtop{...} % they are at one line 
                                 % in the paragraph started by \leavevmode 

\hbox{\vtop{...}\vtop{...}}      % they are at one line in the \hbox.
```

I wrote about TeX modes and boxes in detail in [TeXbook naruby](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/tbn/tbn.pdf), sections 3.4 and 3.5.

IMHO, the "box arithmetic" principles and vertical/horizontal modes are basic knowledges of each TeX users. Unfortunately, LaTeX manuals hides them. LaTeX provides only a complicated construct like `\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}`.

Comment: TeXbook naruby is not yet translated to English I would assume.  I'd love to read it otherwise.

Comment: @AFeldman TeXbook naruby in not translated to English because my English is bad.

Comment: No so bad :) Your answer, for instance, is very understandable, and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard `\parbox` and `\makebox` commands.

There is a subtle point that you seem to be overlooking: the baselineskip might be not uniform with a `\vtop` (or `\parbox[t]`, which is the same) approach.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,letterpaper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[textwidth=5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya}[SmallCapsFont=Alegreya SC]

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newsavebox{\feldA}\newsavebox{\feldB}

\newcommand{\Lcv}[2]{%
  \par
  \hspace*{-1.3in}%
  \makebox[2in][r]{\itshape #1}%
  \hspace*{0.5in}%
  \makebox[3in][l]{#2}%
  \par
}

\newcommand{\Lup}[2]{%
  \sbox\feldA{\parbox[t]{2in}{\itshape#1\par\xdef\tpdA{\the\prevdepth}}}%
  \sbox\feldB{\parbox[t]{3in}{#2\par\xdef\tpdB{\the\prevdepth}}}%
  \ifdim\dp\feldA=\dp\feldB
    \ifdim\tpdA>\tpdB\let\tpdF\tpdA\else\let\tpdF\tpdB\fi
  \else
    \ifdim\dp\feldA>\dp\feldB
      \let\tpdF\tpdA
    \else
      \let\tpdF\tpdB
    \fi
  \fi
  \Lcv{\usebox{\feldA}}{\usebox{\feldB}}\par
  \prevdepth\tpdF
}

\begin{document}

\Lup{Hello this is your Crazy Uncle Unnamed ddd ddd ddd}
    {Who joined the mob to feel good about himself}

Hello and \\ Welcome to {\itshape my} World!!

\Lup{Hello this is your Crazy Uncle Harry yyy yyy yyy yyy}
    {Who joined the mob to feel good about himself}

Hello and \\ Welcome to {\itshape my} World!!

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's easy to see what goes wrong without the fuss with `\prevdepth`: just comment the line `\prevdepth=\tpdF` and you'll get

[image]

Comment: What a great answer!  So if I understand (somewhat) your answer, the baseline skip to the next paragraph after the box is determined by the depth of the second box shipped out, both with a `vtop` and `parbox`.  So, per your answer, you determine which of the 2 boxes has greater depth; then "swap" the depth reporter for box A, with the depth reporter for box B, if box A's depth is greater than that of box B?

Comment: @AFeldman Indeed: I store away the depth of the final lines in both boxes; then look which one has the greater “global depth”, because it's the one that will count for the correct spacing; after the `\par`, I reset the `\prevdepth` to the relevant value.

Comment: Your code is regular tex--latex.  I wonder what this would look like in e-tex? And I bet that a lua version would be interesting too.

Comment: @AFeldman Not much different. But `\parbox` does many more thing than `\vtop`; using the primitive in LaTeX is best avoided. That's why I rejected your edit. If you are interested in a plain TeX answer, please ask a new question.

Comment: My bad.  I should have known that if you wanted to present it that way, you would have.